# Defold what should be part of self

Tags: methods, lua, field, self, defold

What should I put as fields and methods of self in game objects?
Should I put position and velocity as fields? What methods should I put in self?
What should be fields of ob?
Should I put velocity and position as

**self.velocity = vmath.vector3()**

or something like

**go.velocity = vmath.vector3()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` object is a Lua userdata storage for script instance values. What you put there is completely up to you. The nice thing about storing values in `self` is that the `self` object is passed to all of the lifecycle functions of the script (init, final, update, on_input, on_message, on_reload). This means that you have quick access to the variables in all of the functions.

Storing the velocity in self is a good example of something that you may want to access and modify in different places in your script. For instance setting the velocity to some value in on_input when a button is pressed and then use the same velocity value in update to move the object.

> go.velocity = vmath.vector3()

This is not good. What you are doing there is to assign the variable `velocity` to the globally accessible `go.*` namespace containing engine provided functions to manipulate game objects.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have three ways of declaring variables in game object scripts:

1. name = 'Felipe' (Global variable)
2. local name = 'Felipe' (Local variable :v)
3. self.name = 'Felipe' (This one must be inside of a method (init, update, on_message...))

Are they all the same? Answer: **NO**.

**Global variables**:
If you declare a global variable in a script, then you can read and modify that variable in any other script.

```
*hero.script* --- (component of hero.go)

power = 100
```

```
*enemy.script* --- (component of enemy.go)

print(power) -- 100
power = power + 50
print(power) -- 150
```

**Local variables**: if you declare a local variable in a script and then you assign that script to two different game objects, they will share that variable.

```
*hero.script*

local power = 100

function on_message(self, message_id, message, sender)
    if message_id == hash('drink_poison') then
        power = power / 2
    end
end
```

Now we add ./hero.script component to hero.go and knight.go

```
*enemy.script* --- (component of enemy.go)

print(power) -- undefined
```

```
*controller.script* --- (component of controller.go)

msg.post('hero', 'drink_poison')

-- (hero.go): power -> 50
-- but because knight and hero share the same script and power was declared locally then:
-- (knight.go): power -> 50
```

**Self.variables**: self variables create unique copies for each game object the script is assigned to.

```
*hero.script*

function init(self)
    self.power = 100
end

function on_message(self, message_id, message, sender)
    if message_id == hash('drink_poison') then
        self.power = self.power / 2
    end
end
```

Now we add ./hero.script component to hero.go and knight.go

```
*enemy.script* --- (component of enemy.go)

print(power) -- undefined
print(self.power) -- undefined
```

```
*controller.script* --- (component of controller.go)

msg.post('hero', 'drink_poison')

-- (hero.go): power -> 50
-- (knight.go): power -> 100
```